# Using php variables in sql from different php blocks (Undefined variable: xxxx)

Tags: php, sql

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc1bppUlqps) tutorial on how to modify a sql database. Everything seems fine in that but when i run my code below i get an error saying undefined index in line 11 and 12 are not defined. Can anybody point my mistake? Can i even use variable from one block in another?(the guy in the tutorial does)

```
<?php
include '/connection.php';
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
$query="SELECT * FROM SHOP WHERE ID=$_GET[id]";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$shop=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
<form action="modify.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo $shop['name']; ?>">  //error here 
    <input name="city" value="<?php echo $shop['city']; ?>">  //and here
    <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name=submit value="modify">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$q1="UPDATE shop SET name='$_POST[name]',city='$_POST[city]' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
   mysqli_query($conn,$q1)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

Comment: Terrible tutorial, don't follow that, any tutorial that tells you to put user provided data directly into your query is horrid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Its a beginners tutorial dude! no one cares bot security there! chill!

Comment: Okay, then begin with horrible practices. Good luck with that.

Comment: u expect him to cover injection, passwords everything?

Comment: Anyway @chris85 thanks for directing me to that link... I will need it later!

Answer (score 0):

**Try to  read and use parametrized queries (PDI or mysqli) as these are vulnerable for sql injection.**

You need to define $shop=array("shop"=>"","city"=>""); on top of page:

```
<?php
    include '/connection.php';
    $shop=array("shop"=>"","city"=>"");
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query="SELECT * FROM SHOP WHERE ID=$_GET[id]";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $shop=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
    ?>
    <form action="modify.php" method="POST">
        <input name="name" value="<?php echo $shop['name']; ?>">  //error here 
        <input name="city" value="<?php echo $shop['city']; ?>">  //and here
        <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name=submit value="modify">
    </form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q1="UPDATE shop SET name='$_POST[name]',city='$_POST[city]' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
       mysqli_query($conn,$q1)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    ?>
```

OR you can put isset like this:

```
<?php
    include '/connection.php';

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query="SELECT * FROM SHOP WHERE ID=$_GET[id]";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $shop=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }
    ?>
    <form action="modify.php" method="POST">
        <input name="name" value="<?php if(isset($shop['name'])) echo $shop['name']; ?>">  //error here 
        <input name="city" value="<?php if(isset($shop['city'])) echo $shop['city']; ?>">  //and here
        <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name=submit value="modify">
    </form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $q1="UPDATE shop SET name='$_POST[name]',city='$_POST[city]' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
       mysqli_query($conn,$q1)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No mention of SQL injection issues?

Comment: solved! mostly a problem with database cuz the index doesn't exist as @Danish Bhayani said!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the shop variable does not have the required indexes. try this:

```
<?php
include '/connection.php';
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM SHOP WHERE ID=$_GET[id]";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $shop=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
<form action="modify.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo isset($shop['name']) ? $shop['name'] : ''; ?>">
    <input name="city" value="<?php echo isset($shop['city']) ? $shop['city'] : ''; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name=submit value="modify">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $q1="UPDATE shop SET name='$_POST[name]',city='$_POST[city]' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
    mysqli_query($conn,$q1)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

Comment: could you also explain the source of the error. Why is 'shop' empty array(or why is the query returning nothing)? Is it a problem with the 'query' syntax because the database is fine.

Comment: try to debug your $query to get the actual query. Is your $_GET[id] coming fine?

Comment: I switched back to my original code and added a  `header("Location: index.php");` after line 18(just before closing the last if) and it works perfectly... No error... why?

Comment: It is kindof long... But all index.php does is display all rows... I moved the disccusion with index.php <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566598/why-is-absence-of-header-statement-in-php-causing-error">here</a> as it is irrelavent to what i asked here.